# Joomla Users Table

Tags: joomla

I need to update a website created by another developer.  The main user logic of this website is written in Perl and I've made changes as needed to that code.  The previous developer built the major user interface using Joomla. I've recently observed that there are many rows in JOS_USERS that seem to have nothing to do with the company's clients.

I am totally new to Joomla. My question is a VERY BASIC one.  What is Joomla's logic for inserting rows into its user table?  That is, what interaction with a Joomla-based website would cause a row to be inserted into the Joomla user table?

Thanks in advance.

ptm

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.   User registration will add rows to the user table (like almost every web application).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert rows into the `jos_users` table in [several ways](https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase). A common way is like-

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$columns = array('name', 'username', 'email', 'password');
$values = array($db->q('John Doe'), $db->q('johndoe'), $db->q('john@doe.com'), $db->q(md5('secret')));

$query->insert($db->qn('#__users'))
    ->columns($db->qn($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

Here the `$db->q()` and `$db->qn()` are the aliases of the `$db->quote()` and `$db->quoteName()` respectively.

And note that, **Joomla! 3.x** uses `md5` for hashing passwords. So you must have to hash your password using `md5`.